# Accelerated life test of rechargeable batteries

Tags: batteries

How can I perform accelerated life test of rechargeable batteries?
How can I compare 2 different brands of batteries in accelerated life test?

Comment: What things would you like to test?  Just capacity?  Durability over a wide temperature range?  Ability to recover after charging abuse?  Pick a decent battery manufacturer and the datasheet will usually show lifetimes for both constant and pulse loads.

Comment: First decide what you want to know, then look up similar ones online. Or failing that design your own test. If you have a specific application in mind base it around that. Of course you would discharge them at higher rates to be quicker.The harder part is measuring the self discharge. How much you want to do depends on how much time and money you want to spend.

Comment: You could charge them to a certain voltage, measure the resistance. Then discharge them with constant current until a certain voltage and measure the resistance again.